# Removing rows of groups based on different row conditions

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, zoo

This is what my dataframe looks like.

```
dt <- read.table(text='

                         Name      ActivityType   GrpID                 
                         John       Sale           1            
                         John       Sale           2              
                         John       Webinar        3           
                         Kyle       Email          1       
                         Kyle       Seminar        2            
                         Kyle       Sale           3          
                         Kyle       Webinar        4
                         Kyle       Sale           5        
                         Tom        Email          1             
                         Tom        Video          2            
                         Tom        Seminar        3           
                                             ', header=T, row.names = NULL)
```

I want to do 3 things.

1. Removing rows where the group's(Name is the group) first ActivityType is "Sale". That removes rows where Name = John
2. Removing rows where there is no ActivityType = Sale. That removes rows where Name = Tom
3. Return the remaining group where the first ActivityType is NOT "Sale" BUT there is an ActivityType = "Sale" in some later row(as described in 1 & 2) AND only show the results upto the first instance of ActivityType = Sale. So it should show

   ```
               Name      ActivityType   GrpID
                Kyle       Email          1       
                Kyle       Seminar        2            
                Kyle       Sale           3
   ```

   It does not have to be 3 steps as described. I just need the final output. I was thinking about using SD function in data.table but dont know how to add those conditions. I will sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `data.table`:

```
setDT(dt)

sl <- "Sale" #since we re-use it so much...
#1)
dt[ , if (!ActivityType[1L] == sl) .SD, by = Name]

#2)
dt[ , if (any(ActivityType == sl)) .SD, by = Name]

#3)
dt[ , {x <- ActivityType == sl; if(!x[1] & any(x)) .SD[1:which.max(x)]}, by = Name]
```

(note that the third case subsumes the first two, so I'm assuming you want three different outputs... otherwise just stick to the last)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @gibbz00 in the spirit of `data.table` efficiency, note that `1:which.max(x)` has the potential to create an unnecessarily large vector; this phrase could be replaced for efficiency (at the loss of readability) by `{n <- which.max(x); if (n <= .N) 1:n else -(n + 1):.N}`. Basically, we choose whether to _include_ rows or _exclude_ rows based on which entails declaring less elements (for each group created by `by`)

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` this will work on your example above

```
dt %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    filter( sum((GrpID == 1 & ActivityType=='Sale')) == 0 ) %>%
    filter( sum(ActivityType=='Sale') > 0 ) %>%
    filter( GrpID <= min(GrpID[ActivityType == 'Sale'])) %>%
    ungroup

#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#
#    Name ActivityType GrpID
#  (fctr)       (fctr) (int)
#1   Kyle        Email     1
#2   Kyle      Seminar     2
#3   Kyle         Sale     3
```

There may be a cleaner way to do this though.

**EDIT:**  I added the output and `ungroup` to remove the grouping.

**EDIT 2:** Based on the suggestion from MichaelChirico

```
dt %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    filter( !any(ActivityType == 'Sale' & GrpID == 1) )  %>% # 1
    filter(  any(ActivityType == 'Sale') )               %>% # 2
    filter( GrpID <= min(GrpID[ActivityType == 'Sale'])) %>% # 3
    ungroup
```

The above solution uses `any` instead of `sum` (the `%>%` is the pipe operator).  That is not to say this can't be made more efficient though.  I will gladly update this again if someone suggests a more efficient and / or more readable `dplyr` solution.

**EDIT 3**

Below is an alternate solution for item 3 based on a comment/solution by @MichaelChirico.  This combined all 3 conditions in one filter statement (not using the progressive filtering above).

```
dt %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(x = (ActivityType == 'Sale') ) %>%
    filter( !x[1],
            any(x),
            row_number() <= which.max(x))  %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: I believe your answer could be improved by translating some of the stuff in mine (e.g. using `any` instead of `sum`). It also seems wasteful to have to calculate the logical vector 3 separate times; does `dplyr` not have a way to save that and pass it through the pipes?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion MichaelChirico.  As mentioned in the edit `%>%` is the pipe operator used by dplyr (I believe originally from the "magrittr" package).

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing; sorry, I sent that comment from a phone. You'll note that `ActivityType == 'Sale'` is calculated three separate times. One solution to this is to change `#1` to: `(x <<- ActivityType == 'Sale') & GrpID == 1)` then replace `ActivityType == 'Sale'` with `x` thereafter. This doesn't seem quite right either, though, and I'm wondering if there's a more `dplyr`-ish way of doing that. Also, if I'm not mistaken, you can replace the last line with `GrpID <= which.max(ActivityType == 'Sale')` (or `x` if that approach works)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Ok, understood.  I would need to dig a bit to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this.  One comment though is that the second filter will only see a subset of data returned by the first filter (and so on).  So the comparisons are not the same size with the way I have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
# For those who prefer to roll their own
result.list <- by(dt, dt$Name, FUN = function(x) {
  f <- match("Sale", x$ActivityType)
  if(!is.na(f) & (f != 1) ) return(head(x, f))
})

result.df <- do.call(rbind, result.list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!